# MATERIAL TEXTURING PROBLEM

Tags: texturing, materials

I am new to Blender and I just wanted to ask you if anyone has a clue about why do the kitchen elements made with archipack appear in darker tone than kitchen island and shelving which I modeled from scratch, since they are all linked to same material made with same image texture (particular color code which I wanted to replicate..)? Also differences in color can be seen on the handles which I cutted into the archipack elements doors and I just cant figure out why does the "cut in" appear slightly brighter than the front panels? UV normals are flipped as they should be..

Any kind of advice is more than welcome :) Thanks!

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't write in all caps in the title or body of any posts, it is the written equivalent of shouting, is [harder to read](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Readability) and may be [considered rude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Computing). Please use the [edit] button below the post to change you text into regular case.

Comment: Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "*this*", "*help with*", "*issue*" or "*question about*", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: SOLVED! I have forgotten to unwrap those objects :P